# Output is Mistakenly Zero in c program

Tags: c

I am learning C I decided to make a file that would calculate the surface area and volume of a sphere once its radius was given by the user. However, when I tried compiling the program by typing in:

```
gcc Sphere.c -lm -o Sphere
```

and I enter the radius when I am prompted to, the SA and V output is always zero. What's going on here? I may be overlooking something simple. Here is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double main()
{
    double rad;
    double sa, vol;
    const double pi = 3.141592654;

    printf("enter the radius of the sphere: \n");
    scanf("%f", &rad);

    vol = (4.0/3.0)* pi *(pow(rad,3));
    sa = 4.0 * pi * (pow(rad,3));

    printf("Volume of sphere is: %.3f", vol);
    printf("\n Surface area of sphere is: %.3f", sa);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What on earth is a *vim* file? `main()` does not return `double`, compile your code with `gcc -Wall -Werror -g3 -O0 Sphere.c -o Sphere -lm`, to see that your compiler will shout at you.

Comment: `vim` is a text editor, which is irrelevant.

Comment: @FiddlingBits I know what vim is.

Comment: @iharob Personally, I like `emacs` files better. ;-)

Comment: I never got it and I know that there is an *emacs* command for that, *vim* though I do like.

Comment: I was just trying to be specific in regards to what I was using, however trivial.

Comment: @aniben Please check the update on my answer, there is another problem in your code.

Comment: if, during the compile step, all the warnings were enabled (for gcc, at least '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic'  then the compiler would have told you about two significant problems with the code.  1) main ALWAYS returns int, not double  2) the scanf() has a float input/conversion but the parameter is a double.   Then, when calling scanf() (and family of functions) always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong `scanf()` specifier.

The correct specifier for `double` is `"%lf"`, and `scanf()` returns a value which you are ignoring causing possibly undefined behavior.

Also, `main()` does not have the signature you used, it returns a `int`, not a `double` or anything else, so your code would work if you fix at as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    double rad;
    double sa, vol;
    const double pi = 3.141592654;

    printf("enter the radius of the sphere: \n");
    if (scanf("%lf", &rad) == 1)
    {
        vol = (4.0/3.0)* pi *(pow(rad,3));
        sa = 4.0 * pi * (pow(rad,3));

        printf("Volume of sphere is: %.3f", vol);
        printf("\n Surface area of sphere is: %.3f", sa);
    }
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid Input\n");

    return 0;

}
```

Also, **vim** is a text editor, **gcc** is a compiler, and you are invoking the compiler with the least diagnostic that is possible, I recommend

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -g3 -O0 Sphere.c -o Sphere -lm
```

which will let you know about silly mistakes that you might somtimes make.

**Edit**:

As noticed by @[A.S.H](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30429739/output-is-mistakenly-zero-in-c-program/30429754?noredirect=1#comment48944186_30429754) in the comments below, there is a mistake with the surface area formula it has to be

> A = 4πr<sup>2</sup>

you have

> A = 4πr<sup>3</sup>

which is wrong.

Comment: yay! It worked! Yeah, I knew I overlooked something I hadn't learned yet. Thanks.

Comment: sa = 4.0 * pi * (pow(rad,3)); // error here: (rad, 2) not (rad, 3) ;)

Comment: @A.S.H true, it has nothing to do with the question though, but it's correct it has to be squared and not cubed for the surface area.

Comment: yes it was not the question, but I thought it would be useful since I noticed it

Comment: Thanks for that as well, although I did notice that once I saw the output.